# Where does the complement of the Cantor set get mapped under the Cantor-Lebesgue function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Defining the Cantor set $C$ in the typical way, and $O=[0,1]\setminus C$, where would the Cantor-Lebesgue function $\varphi$ map $O$?

I believe that the image of $\varphi(C)$ is the entire interval $[0,1]$ (is this correct?), so what would that mean for the image of $\varphi(O)$?

Additionally, $\varphi$ has been defined in the traditional way on $O$, and has been extended to all of $[0,1]$ via $\phi(x)=\sup\{\varphi(t)|t\in O\cap [0,x)\}$.

Comment: Maybe the set of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$?

Comment: I've never heard that terminology before- what are the dyadic rationals?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown for context, I have taken undergraduate Real Analysis I and II, and am currently in a graduate Measure theory course.

Comment: @MathStudent1324 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Comment: @ChrisCulter I appreciate the link, but do you have any suggestions for how I should be thinking about this without having learned that terminology? What is the reasoning behind this answer?

Comment: If you've defined the Cantor set in terms of base-3 expansions, and the Cantor-Lebesgue function in terms of base-3-to-base-2 expansions, then (handwaving) you'll probably end up with some description of numbers with terminating base-2 expansions, if you turn the crank enough. (And the latter happen to be the dyadic rationals).